# Probably easy bug, can't find it, new to python

Tags: python

I made a program. Its homework I assigned to myself, haven't done a whole lot of python, more of a c++ kinda guy. I can't find the bug, I'm just getting a

```
syntax error: invalid syntax line 88
```

The line is `"print "Attenuation Constant = ", Ac"`

```
z = input("The depth in meters = ")
S = input("salinity in p.s.u. = ")
T = input("temperature in C = ")
pH = input("pH = ")
f = input("frequency of the propagating wave = ")

#relaxation of Boric acid
c = 1,412 + (3.21*T) + (1.19*S) + (.0167*Z)
A_1 = (8.86/c)(10**(.78*pH - 5))
P_1 = 1
f_1 = 2.8*sqrt(S/35)*10**(4 - (1245/(T+273)))

#contribution of Magnesium sulphate
A_2 = 21.44(S/c)(1+0.25*T)
P_2 = (1 - 1.37 * 10**(-4)*z) + (6.2*10**(-9)*z**(2))
f_2 = (8.17 * 10**(8-1990/(T+273)))/(0.0018 (S-35)+1)

#contribution of the viscosity of pure water is
P_3 = 1 - (3.83 * 10^(-5) * z ) + (4.9 * 10^(-10) * z**(2))
if T <= 20:
    A_3 = 4.937 * 10**(-4) - 2.590 * 10**(-5) * T + 9.11 * 10**(-7) * T**(2) - 1.5 * 10**(-8) * T**(3)
else:
    A_3 = 3.964 * 10**(-4) - 1.146 * 10**(-5) * T + 1.45 * 10**(-7) * T**(2) - 6.5 * 10**(-10) * T**(3)

#all together now
Ac = A_1 * P_1 * ((f_1 * f**(2)) /(f_1**(2) + f**(2)) + A_2 * P_2 * ((f_2 * f**(2)) /(f_2**(2) + f**(2)) + A_3 * P_3 * f**(2)

print "Attenuation Constant = ", Ac
```

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Comment: I think the `,`is wrong and you need to replace it with `+`, but I'm not in phyton very much.

Comment: Nope the `,` is fine. As @Jordan Trudgett said, you have a parenthesis mismatch.

Answer (score 4):

You're missing some parentheses on the line before, `Ac = ...` at least in the sample given. There are 13 open parens and only 11 close parens.

Answer (score 0):

There are many bugs

1. you declared `z` and you have used it as `Z`
   c = 1,412 + (3.21*T) + (1.19*S) + (.0167*Z)
2. bad use of `/` operator
   `unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'float' and 'tuple'` at `A_1 = (8.86/c)(10**(.78*pH - 5))`
3. `can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'` at line in 2. You may use explicit casting
4. multiplications for `c` creating tuple like `(1, 432.8601)` What you really want here? tuple or values?  Multiplying tuple with int will give error.

please clear what exactly you want so that rest of the things can be corrected.